# Using single query to retrieve multivalued attribute by joining two tables without causing duplication of fields in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, join, crosstab

Table 1 :
*QUERY: Create table client (
 applicationNo int primary key,
 name varchar(20)
);*

*Insert statement: Insert into client values (1,'XYZ'),(1,'ABC'),(1,'DEF');*

```
applicationNo   |   name  
    1           |   XYZ  
    2           |   ABC  
    3           |   DEF
```

Table 2:
*Query : Create table client (
 applicationNo int,
 phoneNo Bigint,
 foreign key (applicationNo) references client (applicationNo),
 primary key(applicationNO,phoneNo)
);*

*Insert into phoneNO values (1,999999),(1,888888),(2,777777),(3,666666),(3,555555);*

```
applicationNo | phoneNo
1             |   999999
1             |   888888
2             |   777777
3             |   666666
3             |   555555
```

Can I retrieve the tuples by joining both the tables in such a way that get the following output, but using single query, also I'm using mysql 5.1

```
applicationNo |   name | phoneNo1 | phoneNo2 
1             |   XYZ  |  999999  |   88888
2             |   ABC  |  77777   |   Null
3             |   DEF  |  66666   |   555555
```

*Edited : extra information*
I tried using this something called cross tab .But I'm not able to use the totalPhoneNo inside the case statement

```
SELECT applicationNo,count(phoneNo) as totalPhoneNo,  
SUM(CASE WHEN totalPhoneNo= 1 THEN phoneNO ELSE Null END) AS phoneNo1,  
SUM(CASE WHEN totalPhoneNO = 2 THEN phoneNo ELSE Null END) AS phoneNo2  
FROM phoneNO GROUP BY applicationNo;
```

Comment: Is there a MAX of 2 phone numbers per applicationNo?

Comment: yes.One client can have maximum of 2 phone nos n min 1 number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select c.applicationNo, 
       max(c.name) name,
       max(p.phoneNo) phoneNo1,
       case 
           when max(p.phoneNo) = min(p.phoneNo) then NULL 
           else min(p.phoneNo) 
       end phoneNo2
from client c
left join phoneNo p on c.applicationNo = p.applicationNo
group by c.applicationNo
```

Comment: yippy success at last!! Thank you Mark :) This worked for me.

Comment: I'm very sorry I can't vote up this answer.It says I require 15 reputations :(
But anyway I thank all you guys who showed interest in answering this question.Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is is for MSSQL. Does this convert nicely?

```
With phones (ApplicationNo, PhoneNo, Instance) as
(Select ApplicationNo, PhoneNo,
  Row_Number OVER (Partition By ApplicationNo) as RowNum)
Select client.ApplicationNo, client.Name, 
  p1.PhoneNo as phoneNo1, p2.PhoneNo as phoneNo2
From client
  Left Join phones p1 on client.ApplicationNo=p1.ApplicationNo as p1.RowNum=1
  Left Join phones p2 on client.ApplicationNo=p2.ApplicationNo as p2.RowNum=2
```

Comment: Hey bill thanks for answering but I'm not able to convert this query into mysql syntax :(.

Answer (score 0):

use subselects with limit clauses. the first subselect picks the first phone the other the second.

```
select ApplicationNo,
(SELECT phoneno FROM phones where phones.applicationno=app.ApplicationNo order by phoneno LIMIT 0, 1)as phone1,
(SELECT phoneno  FROM phones where phones.applicationno=app.ApplicationNo order by phoneno LIMIT 1, 1)as phone2
from application app
```

Comment: hey cody thnx for your answer but the problem is the sub queries pull out the same phone no (the first and the second phnNo in the table ) for every applicatioNO

Comment: I added an alias for "application" and an "order by" for the subselects. Does it work now?